# navigate to each tr input boxes through keypress arrow up down

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).keypress(hover);

function hover(e) {

    var lent = $(".edit_tr").length; //8 
    var sid = $('.edit_tr').attr('id');
    var x = parseInt(sid) + lent;
    if (stat == false) {
        var sid = parseInt(sid) + 1;
    }
    switch (e.keyCode) { //down   

        case 40:

            $("#last_" + sid).hide();
            $("#last_input_" + sid).show();
            $("#sub_input_" + sid).show();
            $("#sub_" + sid).hide();
            $("#sub_input_" + sid).focus();

            var stat = false;
            break;

        case 38:
            //up

            $("#last_" + sid).show();
            $("#last_input_" + sid).hide();
            $("#sub_input_" + sid).hide();
            $("#sub_" + sid).show();
            $("#sub_input_" + sid).blur();
            break;
    }
}
```

i want to navigate through keypress arrow/up and down in each tr's input text how can i navigate them base on the id from the tr? i am new to jquery

Comment: can you reframe your question ? bit in simple words that is clear to understand pls..

Comment: Is my answer what you wanted? @user3143564

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zBjrS/1/ just like these but my input text's id are based on the id of tr how to i do it

Answer (score 0):

In-order to move, it's pretty simple.

To move it up:

```
    case 38:
        //up

        $("#last_" + sid).show();
        $("#last_input_" + sid).hide();
        $("#sub_input_" + sid).hide();
        $("#sub_" + sid).show();
        $("#sub_input_" + sid).blur();
        $("#idtomove").css('margin-top','-=10px');
        break;
```

In this code, I reduced the margin of top by 10px so each time you press up button, the div will move up by 10 pixels; And the bottom one, move's the item you want to move down by 10px;

```
case 40:

            $("#last_" + sid).hide();
            $("#last_input_" + sid).show();
            $("#sub_input_" + sid).show();
            $("#sub_" + sid).hide();
            $("#sub_input_" + sid).focus();
            $("#idtomove").css('margin-top','+=10px');
            var stat = false;
            break;
```